# Allow subfolder files but not subfolder Robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

In my Robots.txt I have to allow all the files in side a particular sub folder. But it should not allow to crawl that sub folder. Is that possible with Robots.txt. I found for folder and subfolder like

```
  Disallow: /directory/ 
Allow: /directory/subdirectory/
```

Is this the same way for subfolder and files?.. if yes I have to allow all the files inside that sub-directory. How to implement that?

Comment: Is robots.txt only being read by the server and not going to be read by the client/browser ever?

Comment: If you're just trying to prevent scanning the directory (i.e. getting a list of files), then you turn off directory listings. That's not a function of robots.txt. See, for example, https://www.golemtechnologies.com/articles/disable-directory-listing. Or, for IIS, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @Jim Mischel. No i want google to access the files inside that directory but not that directory

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Please give examples of files you want Googlebot to see, and those that you don't want Googlebot to see.

Comment: I have a folder like 'test' and having file inside it like test.php i.e., test/test.php..... google should access test/test.php but should not access test/....

Answer (score 1):

The directive:

```
Disallow: /*test/$
```

Will tell the bot that it can't access the directory `test/`. The `$` means "end of string." So `"http://example.com/test/"` would be blocked, but `"http://example.com/test/foo.php"` would be allowed.

You probably should also add:

```
Disallow: /*test$
```

See the section marked "URL matching based on path values" in [Google's robots.txt documentation](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache, you can write folder permissions like this:

```
<FilesMatch robots.txt>
  Order deny, allow
  Allow from localhost
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

If you don't need Apache to read robots.txt at all, you can just reject completely. Alternatively, you could use `chmod` and change the settings so Apache simply cannot read the file.